# omnipay and pacnet payment integration

Tags: laravel

Hello i am using omnipay package for payment. I install it with composer and try to use in laravel 4.

use Omnipay\Omnipay;

```
class ConfirmationController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {

       $gateway = Omnipay::create('Pacnet');
       echo '<pre>';
       dd($gateway);
       echo '</pre>';
        $gateway->setApiKey('abc123');
```

Where i can find some examples for using pacnet, this is stripe package example, and got error unknown method serApiKey. Can someone provide me some documentation or example.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using stripe as payment gateway?

Comment: no pacnet i need pacnet

Comment: Suggest that you add the omnipay tag to this question. The omnipay devs including myself usually scan for that tag.